# Convert string to float in Python ' 0,3638412'

Tags: python, string, floating-point, voronoi

Im trying to convert a string to a float

with the float function:

```python
   pointsx = float(x)
```

got error:

```python
>ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 0,3638412'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
pointsx = float(x.replace( ',', '.'))
```

Floating point numbers use dot `.` as a separator, not the comma.

Answer (score 0):

you are applying the correct method but are you sure the value of x is '0,3638412'.
if it is wrong then you need to change the value of x.

```
x = '0.3638412'
pointsx = float(x)
```

if it is right then the code given below solves your value.

```
pointsx = float(x.replace(',','.'))
```